# Using grunt, how do I run three blocking tasks concurrently?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have succesfully combined `grunt-contrib-watch` with `grunt-nodemon` using `grunt-concurrent` to allow me to autostart my node.js instance whenever I edit and transpile my coffeescript files.

Here is the `grunt-concurrent` portion of the gruntfile that I use to achieve this:

**gruntfile.coffee**

```
concurrent:
  dev:
    tasks: [
      'watch'
      'nodemon'
    ]
    options: 
      logConcurrentOutput: true
```

The `watch` and `nodemon` tasks are configured in the same file but have been removed for brevity. This work fine.

Now I want to add a `grunt-node-inspector` to the list of concurrent tasks. Like so:

```
concurrent:
  dev:
    tasks: [
      'watch'
      'nodemon'
      'node-inspector'
    ]
    options: 
      logConcurrentOutput: true
```

According to the `grunt-nodemon` help file at least, this should be possible as it is given as an example usage: [Running Nodemon Concurrently](https://github.com/ChrisWren/grunt-nodemon#running-nodemon-concurrently)

However this does not work for me. Instead only the first two tasks are started.

Experiments show that `grunt-concurrent` appears to be limited to running only two tasks concurrently. Any subsequent tasks are ignored. I have tried various options, for example:

```
concurrent:
  dev1:[
      'watch'
      'nodemon'
    ]
  dev2:[
      'node-inspector'
    ]        
    options: 
      logConcurrentOutput: true

grunt.registerTask 'default', ['concurrent:dev1', 'concurrent:dev2']
```

I also have tried setting the `limit` option to 3. I had high hopes for this so maybe I have misunderstood how to apply the value correctly:

```
concurrent:
  dev:
    limit: 3
    tasks: [
      'watch'
      'nodemon'
      'node-inspector'
    ]
    options: 
      logConcurrentOutput: true
```

But I cannot get my third blocking task to run.

**Question**
How can I get all three blocking tasks running at the same time?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you read https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent#limit, do you specify a limit? If not, are you using a dual core or multicore set to pretend it's only one? If so, problem found.

Comment: Typo on `dev1` fixed. I had tried the `limit` option to no effect and have now included that example as well. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the limit value in the option, like so:

```
concurrent: {
    tasks: ['nodemon', 'watch', 'node-inspector'],
    options: {
        limit: 5,
        logConcurrentOutput: true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm. I also had to set the `limit : 4` in order to get three tasks to run.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using grunt.util.spawn to run my tasks and include the 1 blocking call at the end.
http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.util#grunt.util.spawn
http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events

This block kills the children.

```
var children = [];

process.on('SIGINT', function(){
    children.forEach(function(child) {
        console.log('killing child!');
        child.kill('SIGINT');
    });
});

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    'use strict';
```

...

Then I register a task

```
grunt.registerTask('blocked', 'blocking calls', function() {
    var path = require('path')
    var bootstrapDir = path.resolve(process.cwd()) + '/bootstrap';
    var curDir = path.resolve(process.cwd());

    children.push(
        grunt.util.spawn( {
            cmd: 'grunt',
            args: ['watch'],
            opts: {
                cwd: bootstrapDir,
                stdio: 'inherit',
            }
        })
    );

    children.push(
        grunt.util.spawn( {
            cmd: 'grunt',
            args: ['nodemon'],
            opts: {
                cwd: curDir,
                stdio: 'inherit',
            }
        })
    );

    children.push(
        grunt.util.spawn( {
            cmd: 'grunt',
            args: ['node-inspector'],
            opts: {
                cwd: curDir,
                stdio: 'inherit',
            }
        })
    );

    grunt.task.run('watch');
});
```

In your case, you can change the current working dir to the gruntfile.js and run multiple instances.